# Maui.CSharpMath.SkiaSharp Canvas trying to draw too large bitmap

Tags: maui, android-canvas, android-bitmap, skiasharp

I am using Maui and library CSharpMath.SkiaSharp and MathPainter from there too create latex formulas. I have an editor where the user enters latex. Using MathPainter, I draw the latex formula as a stream and show it to the user in real time with a picture, the source of this picture changes as soon as the formula changes. It looks something like this:

```
MathPainter mathPainter = new() {FontSize = 25};

private void EditorTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string formula = e.NewTextValue;
   mathPainter.LaTeX = formula;
   LatexImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mathPainter.DrawAsStream())
}
```

Then, when the user is done and clicks the button, I get the picture again as a stream and save it in the place I need. Sometimes it works as expected, but most of the time I just get the "Canvas trying to draw too large bitmap" exception and the application crashes. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I do not know about LaTeX or MathPainter, but this is very common android exception. It means exactly what it says - you are drawing too big image. (Like 3000x3000). I doubt that there wont be some sort of configuration for the canvas of this "LaTex/MathPainter". And if by any chance there isn't - you can always resize it before setting it as source.

Comment: @H.A.H. Math painter include configurations like image style, i mean font size, colors, errors and others. If we talking about DrawAsStream() method, there is just canvas width , aligment, image format(png, jpeg and others) and also image quality. Can you advise me the best way how can i resize my image before setting it as source?

Comment: What do you mean "just canvas width"? Canvas width is exactly what you want. Set it to something small (like 300).

Comment: Either the method, or the object will have some way to be configured. I am 99.99% sure. It cannot be designed that stupid. I mentioned manually resizing so you know, that even if there isn't, you still have the option to make your picture smaller, before trying to render it. But it has to be a way to configure this library to draw smaller image at first place. Read the docs.

Comment: @H.A.H. i tried with different canvas width options, but nothing changed. I read docs, but its using controls, which is not represented in maui, just for Xamarin. As I understand, the onliest way is to use draw as stream method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here we go:

This is the source code of DrawAsStream:

```
public static System.IO.Stream? DrawAsStream<TContent>
  (this Painter<SKCanvas, TContent, SKColor> painter,
   float textPainterCanvasWidth = TextPainter.DefaultCanvasWidth,
   TextAlignment alignment = TextAlignment.TopLeft,
   SKEncodedImageFormat format = SKEncodedImageFormat.Png,
   int quality = 100) where TContent : class {
  var size = painter.Measure(textPainterCanvasWidth).Size;
  // SKSurface does not support zero width/height. Null will be returned from SKSurface.Create.
  if (size.Width is 0) size.Width = 1;
  if (size.Height is 0) size.Height = 1;
  using var surface = SKSurface.Create(new SKImageInfo((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height));
  painter.Draw(surface.Canvas, alignment);
  using var snapshot = surface.Snapshot();
  return snapshot.Encode(format, quality).AsStream();
}
```

This line here:

```
var size = painter.Measure(textPainterCanvasWidth).Size;
```

Returns the same result over and over.
(This textPainterCanvasWidth says "UNUSED")

So, what do we do?
We copy this method and write our own:

```
Stream GetStream(MathPainter painter)
{
    var size = painter.Measure(100).Size; //This returns the same
    size.Width = 300;
    size.Height = 300;
    if (size.Width is 0) size.Width = 1;
    if (size.Height is 0) size.Height = 1;
    using var surface = SKSurface.Create(new SKImageInfo((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height));
    painter.Draw(surface.Canvas, CSharpMath.Rendering.FrontEnd.TextAlignment.Center);
    using var snapshot = surface.Snapshot();
    return snapshot.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100).AsStream();
}
```

And override the Width and Height to 300 in it.

In the XAML we have:

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Aspect="AspectFit" WidthRequest="500" HeightRequest="500"/>
```

And in the code:

```
myImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => GetStream(mathPainter));
```

It works on my side, more or less.